# How to compute the matrix of the sum of two dice rolls in R?

Tags: r

Is there an idiomatic way to compute the sum of two dice rolls in R, as a matrix?

This is the output I am seeking:

```
      [1]  [2]  [3]  [4]  [5]  [6]
[1]    2    3    4    5    6    7
[2]    3    4    5    6    7    8
[3]    4    5    6    7    8    9
[4]    5    6    7    8    9   10
[5]    6    7    8    9   10   11
[6]    7    8    9   10   11   12
```

Comment: `sapply(1:6, function(i) 1:6 + i)`

Comment: `matrix(rep(1:6,  36) + rep(1:6, each = 6), 6, 6)`

Comment: idiomatic you say? well `i<-diag(6);row(i)+col(i)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The outer function is designed for taking the outer product of two vectors, but you can switch the function to "+".

```
outer(1:6, 1:6, "+")
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base R option besides `outer`, using `replicate`

```
r <- t(replicate(6,1:6))+1:6
```

or

```
r <- (u <- replicate(6,1:6)) + t(u)
```

such that

```
> r
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    2    3    4    5    6    7
[2,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
[3,]    4    5    6    7    8    9
[4,]    5    6    7    8    9   10
[5,]    6    7    8    9   10   11
[6,]    7    8    9   10   11   12
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sapply(seq(6), "+", seq(6))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    2    3    4    5    6    7
#[2,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
#[3,]    4    5    6    7    8    9
#[4,]    5    6    7    8    9   10
#[5,]    6    7    8    9   10   11
#[6,]    7    8    9   10   11   12
```